# Jquery script conflict or not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my prestashop website I added the infinity scroller script and it work perfect. this is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/modules/infinitescroll/js/jquery.infinitescroll.dev.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/modules/infinitescroll/behaviors/masonry-isotope.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    infinite_scroll = {"loading":{"msgText":"","finishedMsg":"<em>No additional posts.<\/em>","img":"http:\/\/demo.boonex.com\/templates\/base\/images\/loading.gif"},"nextSelector":"#pagination_next > a","navSelector":".pagination","itemSelector":"#tiles > li","contentSelector":"#tiles","debug":true,"behavior":"masonry","callback":""};
        infinite_scroll.maxPage = 8;
        jQuery( infinite_scroll.contentSelector ).infinitescroll( infinite_scroll, function(newElements, data, url) { eval(infinite_scroll.callback); });
</script>
```

The above script is for INFINITY SCROLLER:

**SO MY PROBELM IS**

I have this simple jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".item").hover(function () {
            $(this).find(".over").fadeToggle(1);
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>
```

it makes a simple **hover** effect on each product. And it works on the **first page ONLY**, after i scroll down and Infinity scoller script start working, my **HOVER** code is not working anymore.

**So why this happens? And how can I fix this problem?**

PS: I have deleted all extra javascript plugins from the HEAD...

**this is what CONSOLE shows:**

Before scrolling:
[image]

after scrolling:
[image]

Comment: can you see if you are getting any JS errors in the console?

Comment: Next set of items are dynammicaly generated a?

Comment: hover event does not fire or the code inside it does not work ? also, can you create a jsfiddle so that i can check....!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems dynamic generated content after scroll not binding the hover event.

bind the hover event using delegate:

```
$('#mainContainer').on('mouseenter', '.item', function(){
  $(this).find(".over").fadeToggle(1);
   return false;
});
```

and reverse above code on mouseleave.

Comment: @Andrei i know this only the problem i asked question in comment section you not respond..

Answer (score 0):

Delegate the event to a static parent element.

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.item', function () {
    $(this).find(".over").fadeToggle(1);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Yours is similar with "MUKESH" except that "mouseenter" works better, at list for me!